# Align <li> vetically

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown in the form of `<ul> <li>`
[image]

The problem is that as you can see that the `<li>`  are horizontal.I want it to be placed vertically. Like

```
Districts
Culture
Tourism
```

Current CSS is like:

```
.sub-menu {
    max-width: 450px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #51A8DD;
    background-color: cyan;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Please help me align my `<li>'s` vertically

Comment: `li`'s are vertical by default. You didn't include all of the relevant html and css to replicate the issue. Please give us the code that will reproduce your current layout.

Comment: Do you want something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_fixed?

Comment: display:block for li tag should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
li {
    display: block;
}
```

This is the default for **li** elements, so have a look elsewhere in your code to see if it is set differently (e.g. to **display: inline**, somewhere.

Hope this helps!